# Cannot access statusCode in Angular 5 and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I have a service which makes a POST request to an action in Core:

```
this.http.post(url, loginModel).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.statusCode === 200) { // here I got typescript error that `statusCode` does not belong to Object
        this.route.navigateByUrl("/main");
      }
});
```

and MVC action:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
        {
            return Json(Ok());
        }
}
```

The response I got in console is:

```
{statusCode: 200}
```

How to fix the typescript error ? What should I do ?

The error looks like:

> ERROR in .../login/login.service.ts(21,20): error TS2339: Property
>   'statusCode' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default your `http` return `observable<Object>`, to have better control, strong cast like this :

```
this.http.post<{statusCode:number}>(url, loginModel).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.statusCode === 200) { // here is available
        this.route.navigateByUrl("/main");
      }
});
```

For more complexe API answer :

```
export interface ResponseModel {
    statusCode: number;
    other: string;
    thing: string;
}

this.http.post<ResponseModel>(url, loginModel).subscribe(result => {
      // Where you can consume result as ResponseModel type.
});
```

Comment: well explained answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When working with **HttpClient**, I also faced that same problem. It occurs because **httpClient** return `Observable<Object>` to bypass this problem I use it this way,

```
this.http.post<any>(url, loginModel)
    .subscribe(result => {
         console.log(result);
         if (result.statusCode === 200) {
           this.route.navigateByUrl("/main");
         }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you need to parse the response first in the JSON format and then subscribe to it so that you will be able to use `result.statusCode` in your method call.

so Use this Code :

```
this.http.post(url, loginModel)
  .map(data => data.json())
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result && result.statusCode === 200) { // here I got typescript error that `statusCode` does not belong to Object
      this.route.navigateByUrl("/main");
    }
});
```

Comment: May I Know what is wrong with this answer? why downvote ?